# PostgreSQL - ensure each element of an array is unique

Tags: arrays, json, database, postgresql

I have a table "json_test" in PostgreSQL 9.6, for simplicity, it has only 2 columns: *id* of type int8 and *json* of type json.

The json column should contain an array of json objects like `[{key1: val1}, {key2: val2}]`.

How can I constrain the table to ensure *{key1: val3}* cannot be added to this specific row as *key1* already exists.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you need constraints like that, this is a good indicator that you should normalize your data model. Create a one-to-many relationship and define a unique constraint on the many table.

Comment: It was that way before, but there are more than 80 million rows in the child-table, which reduces performance significantly compared to a json array in the parent-table

Comment: I very much doubt that

Comment: like what exaclty? @a_horse_with_no_name